# Parsing a csv file using pandas and group by columns for prediction

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to parse a CSV file that has 1000's of records from a source system continuously. Few lines of which is shown below.

Each row data always total up to 50.

My goal is to parse this CSV and apply a prediction model to see what would be my next row. My expected output is at the last.

My current issues are,

1. I couldn't figure out how to group them successfully and parse them.
2. Pick the right module and run the prediction. how can we test/validate if the model is the right one for this data? I've picked the below module for now and I could do trial and error on that part.

Models:

```
# from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg
# from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMAResults
```

Data CSV:

The CSV file has the latest data at row # 1 (sorted already in desc order of time)

```
S01,S02,S03,S04,S05,S06,S07,S08,S09,S10
6,3,5,8,6,3,6,3,6,4
6,1,4,8,6,3,7,4,7,4
6,1,4,8,8,3,6,3,7,4
6,1,4,7,7,5,5,4,8,3
6,2,4,6,6,5,6,3,8,4
7,2,4,5,6,7,5,3,7,4
8,2,5,4,5,7,4,3,7,5
8,2,5,3,5,7,5,4,6,5
7,2,6,3,5,7,4,5,5,6
8,2,5,2,5,7,7,5,4,5
7,2,6,1,5,6,7,4,4,8
8,2,6,1,5,5,6,4,5,8
7,1,7,1,5,5,6,4,5,9
7,1,7,2,5,5,7,4,4,8
6,1,8,2,5,5,7,5,4,7
5,2,7,2,5,4,8,6,4,7
3,2,7,2,6,5,8,6,5,6
```

Expected Output:

```
Predicted Next row:

8,1,7,3,5,5,4,3,3,11
```

My current snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

dtypes = {
    "S01": "category",
    "S02": "category",
    "S03": "category",
    "S04": "category",
    "S05": "category",
    "S06": "category",
    "S07": "category",
    "S08": "category",
    "S09": "category",
    "S10": "category",            
}


df = pd.read_csv('./parse.csv',dtype=dtypes,usecols=list(dtypes))
print(df)
```